# Postgres Rails 4 search query id or multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am working in an app with a basic search form with Heroku, but I can't get my sql query to work properly with PostgreSQL, even though this query worked with MySQL. By the way, I tried to paste the logs from Heroku, but it only says that when you search something it renders 500.html.

Here's my model OrdemDeServico with the search action:

```
def self.search(search)
   if search
    joins(:cliente).where("clientes.nome LIKE ? OR veiculo LIKE ? OR placa LIKE  ? OR ordem_de_servicos.id = ?", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "#{search}")
   else
    where(nil)
   end
  end
```

I just installed PostgreSQL locally, and it returned this error when searching:

```
`PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Augusto"
LINE 1: ... placa LIKE '%Augusto%' OR ordem_de_servicos.id = 'Augusto')
```

query:

```
SELECT  "ordem_de_servicos".* FROM "ordem_de_servicos" INNER JOIN "clientes" ON "clientes"."id" = "ordem_de_servicos"."cliente_id" WHERE (clientes.nome LIKE '%Augusto%' OR veiculo LIKE '%Augusto%' OR placa LIKE '%Augusto%' OR ordem_de_servicos.id = 'Augusto')  ORDER BY prazo LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: 500 means a server error. There should be more in the logs about where in the code the errors occurs. Can't you just run your website locally instead of using the live version on Heroku to debug this? I think the problem is that you can't just do `where(nil)`

Comment: edwardmp, the problem is I was able to run locally with MySql, but when uploading to heroku I can't get it working. The logs in rails console seems to be ok, but with heroku I can't get a full reading of the logs. And doing where(nil) works fine if I don't add id in my query.

Comment: You aren't joining or including ordem_de_servicos to use the id.

Comment: I am sorry to have not add this information, but this model is OrdemDeServico, which has a relationship with Cliente, that's why I only joined clientes table. With MySQL it worked as a charm, but with PostgreSQL it just doesn't work! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally worked it out a solution. Those who have the same problem here's my code for the model:

```
def self.search(search)
    if search
        where("id = ?", search)
        joins(:cliente).where("clientes.nome ilike :q or veiculo ilike :q or placa ilike :q", q: "%#{search}%")
    else
        where(nil)
    end
end
```